# Flutter web URL navigation like http://localhost:60117/ItemDetails?pId=1 not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

In my flutter project, i have to share a URL which is directly redirect to a particular product details page  through social media . so i have added routing-information using velocity_x, my main.dart page is as follows

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp.router(
  
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'AppName',
  theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: MyAppTheme.primaryColor,
      accentColor:MyAppTheme.accentColor
  ),
routeInformationParser: VxInformationParser(),
routerDelegate: VxNavigator(routes: {

  "/": (_,__)=> MaterialPage(child:SplashScreen()),
  "/login": (_,__)=> MaterialPage(child:SignUp()),
  "/home": (_,__)=> MaterialPage(child:Home(selectedIndex: 0)),
  "/ItemDetails": (uri, _){
    final pId=int.parse(uri.queryParameters["pId"]);     
    return MaterialPage(
      child:ItemDetailsFromAdd(
        pId:pId.toString() ,
      
    ));
  },
  
}),
)
```

My Initial route is splash screen and after checking authentication it redirects to login page or home page. when i click on a particular item, creates a url "http://localhost:60117/ItemDetails?pId=1" this. But when i try to launch this url from another tab, first it load product detail page and suddenly redirects to my initial page splashscreen.

I tried to change "/" initial route from "/" to "/splash" and changed my "`<base href="/splash/">`" but it gives a page not found error initially.

How can i access my product detail page directly using this "http://localhost:60117/ItemDetails?pId=1" URL in correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long testing i found the answer, here my initial route ('/') redirect to the'SplashScreen'. so when i try to access particular item using URL first it comes to SplashScreen and there i coded to redirect to home or Login based on the user authentication. so when i access to a particular item using url it redirect to my login/home. the solution is i changed my initial route to Home page.

Answer (score 2):

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
      List<String> pathComponents = settings.name.split('/');
      if (pathComponents[1] == 'invoice') {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return Invoice(arguments: pathComponents.last);
          },
        );
      } else
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return LandingPage();
          },
        );
      ;
    },
```

Try this way

Comment: i am using velocity_x to routing . how can i add this onGenerateRoute with this code?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by configuring your server to always serve the index.html file for your Flutter web application, regardless of the URL that was requested.

For Apache

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

For Nginx

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

For Firebase

```
 {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "flutter_service_worker.js"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a hashtag `#` to the URL:

```
http://localhost:60117/#/ItemDetails?pId=1
```

It's the only way to share it if you are running a progressive web app. What's the left of the `/#/` tells the browser from where to get the app, and what's after it is the router logic. If you try to remove the `/#/`, the app doesn't behave normally and reverts back to the default route.

Comment: is this format is possible to share through social media? because putting # is used in another way in social media

Comment: It's the only way to share it if you are running a progressive web app. What's the left of the `/#/` tells the browser from where to get the app, and what's after it is the router logic. If you try to remove the `/#/`, the app doesn't behave normally and reverts back to the default route.

Comment: i think he has done something to remove `#`, like using `url_strategy`

Comment: @Huthaifa Muayyad i have added # by removing "setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy());"  but again same issue existing. it redirect to initial route

Comment: You need to have /#/ in your URL if you have a webapp for it to work. This is assuming that you have your routes and parsing configured correctly.

Comment: @Huthaifa Muayyad Do i  need to add anything in index.html ? in my index.html i have  added `<base href="/splash/">`

Comment: You shouldn't have to add anything there for this particular problem.

Comment: @Huthaifa Muayyad i stuck here. any other ways to do this URL navigation?